# WARN [nuxt] Two component files resolving

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt-content

WARN  [nuxt] Two component files resolving to the same name ProseCode:

- ./node_modules/@nuxtjs/mdc/dist/runtime/components/prose/ProseCode.vue
- ./node_modules/@nuxt/content/dist/runtime/components/Prose/ProseCode.vue

WARN  [nuxt] Two component files resolving to the same name ProsePre:

- ./node_modules/@nuxtjs/mdc/dist/runtime/components/prose/ProsePre.vue
- ./node_modules/@nuxt/content/dist/runtime/components/Prose/ProsePre.vue

warning after updated nuxt 3 -> 3.7 & nuxt/content 2.4 -> 2.8

how can this be fixed?
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/2266#issuecomment-1720124274

> There are no warnings logged with Content v2.8.2 and Nuxt v3.7.2 anymore.

So just upgrade to:

- nuxt/content >= 2.8.2 and
- nuxt >= 3.7.2

Make sure to run the following command afterwards

> npx nuxi upgrade --force

It'll delete your lockfile and node_modules folder to make sure you'll get the new versions.

Answer (score 1):

That is likely related to this issue: https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/2266 Nuxt typecheck is broken with nuxt/content@2.8.0 )

Answer (score 1):

This issue is tracked in the nuxt github at https://github.com/nuxt/content/issues/2266

I'm seeing it too so am watching for updates!

edit: Looks like its fixed at nuxt@3.7.2 and upward, I'm no longer seeing it in my build

Answer (score 0):

you shouldn't use two same component names with the same address, warning here that you've done it twice.